# Click a div to change/toggle class on an img

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, accordion

I am stuck with an issue regarding an icon I want to change, when I click on a div. I am trying to make an accordion element with an arrow icon (using Iconoir) that toggles between classes "iconoir-nav-arrow-right" to "iconoir-nav-arrow-down" every time I click on it.

It seems the icon is being added to the div via classList toggle, and not changing the class of the img with class "arrowAcc". Not sure how to use the function to target the img when clicking on div. Perhaps a kind soul here can help me, or point me to a ressource that explains. Thanks a lot in advance!

The code (js, css, html):

```js
function toggleIconAcc(element) {
  element.classList.toggle("iconoir-nav-arrow-right");
  element.classList.toggle("iconoir-nav-arrow-down");
}

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panelAccordion = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panelAccordion.style.maxHeight) {
      panelAccordion.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panelAccordion.style.maxHeight = panelAccordion.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
:root {
    --Lato: "Lato", sans-serif;
    --WorkSans: "Work Sans", sans-serif;
    --hover-color: #084f58;
    --third-color: #028090;
    --fourth-color: #D7FAFE;
    --text-color: #2e2e2e;
    --bggradient: #fffdf5;
    --bggradient2: linear-gradient(220.55deg, #665da1 0%, #418CB7 100%);
    --light-gray: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.877)
}

#faq {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 55%;
    margin: auto;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-top: 16vmin;
}

#faq h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: var(--text-color);
    font-family: var(--WorkSans);
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.accordion {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: var(--fourth-color);
    color: var(--text-color);
    font-family: var(--WorkSans);
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: none;
    padding: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: left;
    transition: 0.25s;
    outline: none;
    margin-top: 4px;
}


.active,
.accordion:hover {
    background-color: var(--hover-color);
    color: #f3f3f3;
}

.panelAccordion {
    padding: 0 18px;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: var(--bggradient);
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/lucaburgio/iconoir@master/css/iconoir.css">
</head>                        
                                                <div id="faq">
                            <h1>Frequently asked questions</h1>
                            <div onclick="toggleIconAcc(this)" class="accordion">
                                <i class="iconoir-nav-arrow-right arrowAcc"></i>
                                <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing?</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panelAccordion">
                                <p class="section-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe
                                    quia asperiores
                                    harum! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur nobis
                                    enim voluptate fugiat officiis similique!
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div onclick="toggleIconAcc(this)" class="accordion">
                                <i class="iconoir-nav-arrow-right arrowAcc"></i>
                                <h4>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum
                                    numquam atque enim?</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panelAccordion">
                                <p class="section-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Dicta
                                    fuga dolore fugiat itaque, a provident. Iste ea optio corporis nostrum, hic
                                    excepturi, ab veritatis iure consequatur sint saepe, distinctio blanditiis
                                    architecto dolorum deleniti.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div onclick="toggleIconAcc(this)" class="accordion">
                                <i class="iconoir-nav-arrow-right arrowAcc"></i>
                                <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet?</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panelAccordion">
                                <p class="section-text">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                                    Repudiandae provident iusto quae? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
                                    elit. Earum tenetur id sapiente amet molestiae assumenda saepe perspiciatis quia quo
                                    deserunt aliquam nemo, aspernatur aperiam tempore excepturi commodi debitis autem
                                    esse! Eum, a.
                                    harum!</p>
                            </div>
                            <div onclick="toggleIconAcc(this)" class="accordion">
                                <i class="iconoir-nav-arrow-right arrowAcc"></i>
                                <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet?</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panelAccordion">
                                <p class="section-text">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                                    Repudiandae provident iusto quae? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
                                    elit. Earum tenetur id sapiente amet molestiae assumenda saepe perspiciatis quia quo
                                    deserunt aliquam nemo, aspernatur aperiam tempore excepturi commodi debitis autem
                                    esse! Eum, a.
                                    harum!</p>
                            </div>
                            <div onclick="toggleIconAcc(this)" class="accordion">
                                <i class="iconoir-nav-arrow-right arrowAcc"></i>
                                <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet?</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panelAccordion">
                                <p class="section-text">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                                    Repudiandae provident iusto quae? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
                                    elit. Earum tenetur id sapiente amet molestiae assumenda saepe perspiciatis quia quo
                                    deserunt aliquam nemo, aspernatur aperiam tempore excepturi commodi debitis autem
                                    esse! Eum, a.
                                    harum!</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: If you are going to call **toggleIconAcc(this)** on click, change **toggleIconAcc()** to **toggleIconAcc(element)** and get rid of the var element in the function. Then make sure EVERY call to toggleIconAcc includes **this** as some do and some don't

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help. I have tried to implement your feedback in the snippet, and the function triggers correctly now when I click on the div, just not exactly with the outcome I am looking for. I was hoping that the class "nav-icon-right" would be removed, and the class "nav-icon-down" would be added on first click. Next click vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your javascript to not be inline but instead to use addEventListener.

One issue that you have in your code is you have TWO click handlers for the accordion element. One is in your javascript and the other is inline but they are being called on the same element.

Cleaning that up and using only one click handler will solve your problems.

Plus you want to toggle iconoir-nav-arrow-right on your icon not the accordion div. Which is what was happening on your inline javascript click handler.

```js
var acc = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion");

acc.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    let icon = this.querySelector("i");
    icon.classList.toggle("iconoir-nav-arrow-right");
    icon.classList.toggle("iconoir-nav-arrow-down");
    let panelAccordion = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panelAccordion.style.maxHeight) {
      panelAccordion.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panelAccordion.style.maxHeight = panelAccordion.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
});
```

```css
:root {
  --Lato: "Lato", sans-serif;
  --WorkSans: "Work Sans", sans-serif;
  --hover-color: #084f58;
  --third-color: #028090;
  --fourth-color: #D7FAFE;
  --text-color: #2e2e2e;
  --bggradient: #fffdf5;
  --bggradient2: linear-gradient(220.55deg, #665da1 0%, #418CB7 100%);
  --light-gray: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.877)
}

#faq {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 55%;
  margin: auto;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-top: 16vmin;
}

#faq h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: var(--text-color);
  font-family: var(--WorkSans);
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.accordion {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: var(--fourth-color);
  color: var(--text-color);
  font-family: var(--WorkSans);
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: none;
  padding: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: left;
  transition: 0.25s;
  outline: none;
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: var(--hover-color);
  color: #f3f3f3;
}

.panelAccordion {
  padding: 0 18px;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: var(--bggradient);
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/lucaburgio/iconoir@master/css/iconoir.css">
</head>
<div id="faq">
  <h1>Frequently asked questions</h1>
  <div class="accordion">
    <i class="iconoir-nav-arrow-right arrowAcc"></i>
    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing?</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="panelAccordion">
    <p class="section-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe quia asperiores harum! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur nobis enim voluptate fugiat officiis similique!
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion">
    <i class="iconoir-nav-arrow-right arrowAcc"></i>
    <h4>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum numquam atque enim?</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="panelAccordion">
    <p class="section-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Dicta fuga dolore fugiat itaque, a provident. Iste ea optio corporis nostrum, hic excepturi, ab veritatis iure consequatur sint saepe, distinctio blanditiis architecto dolorum deleniti.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion">
    <i class="iconoir-nav-arrow-right arrowAcc"></i>
    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet?</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="panelAccordion">
    <p class="section-text">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae provident iusto quae? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum tenetur id sapiente amet molestiae assumenda saepe perspiciatis quia quo deserunt aliquam nemo,
      aspernatur aperiam tempore excepturi commodi debitis autem esse! Eum, a. harum!
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion">
    <i class="iconoir-nav-arrow-right arrowAcc"></i>
    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet?</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="panelAccordion">
    <p class="section-text">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae provident iusto quae? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum tenetur id sapiente amet molestiae assumenda saepe perspiciatis quia quo deserunt aliquam nemo,
      aspernatur aperiam tempore excepturi commodi debitis autem esse! Eum, a. harum!
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion">
    <i class="iconoir-nav-arrow-right arrowAcc"></i>
    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet?</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="panelAccordion">
    <p class="section-text">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae provident iusto quae? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum tenetur id sapiente amet molestiae assumenda saepe perspiciatis quia quo deserunt aliquam nemo,
      aspernatur aperiam tempore excepturi commodi debitis autem esse! Eum, a. harum!
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out, and also explaining the fix. Learning a lot! Have a nice evening.